# How to avoid to type this and set that python 2.7 is default instead of python 2.6?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have access to old linux server(debian) and default Python is 2.6. To start my scripts I need Python 2.7. When I type `python` to console always 2.6 starts
(I have installed 2.7 and when I want to run I use command `pythonbrew use 2.7.2`)

How to avoid to type this and set that Python 2.7 is default?

Answer (score 3):

Specify Python 2.7's executable in the shebang of your scripts. Don't screw with the system Python.

Answer (score 1):

To switch permanently in `pythonbrew` do:

```
~ pythonbrew switch 2.7.2
```

If you are only using some scripts (vs interactively working in the terminal), then it might be a good idea to just add at the top the file:

```
#!/home/user/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-<version>/<name of venv>/bin/python     
                               -- or --
#!/usr/local/pythonbrew/venvs/Python-<version>/<name of venv>/bin/python
```

depending on where your python executable is.